# Why is Robotium not saving screenshots?

Tags: android, automated-tests, robotium

I wrote an automated test for an Android app using Robotium. Everything works except the part where it's supposed to take a screenshot.

I created a `Solo` object and am calling `solo.takeScreenshot()` whenever a screenshot is needed. Robotium is supposed to save them to `sdcard/Robotium-Screenshots` on the device, but there is no `Robotium-Screenshots` directory anywhere. I manually created a directory with that name, but it's always empty. I do have the `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permission enabled as well as root access. There are no error messages when `takeScreenshot()` is called.

Is there anything else I need to do to save screenshots with Robotium?

Comment: What is the version of android device/emulator you are testing on ? For me it works fine on android 4.x 5.x but not on Android 6 and N, probably  because of runtime permissions... investigating.